# Shortest path for a weighted graph, but the weights are a bit special

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra

I am trying to find a shortest path (the cheapest) in a weighted multi-directional graph where the vertices are cities, the edges are routes between cities and the weights are prices.

each route/edge is owned by one of 3 companies. The price is the same for all edges owned by a company. So all edges owned by company 'A' will have a price of X.

So if a final path goes through 2 of company A's routes and 1 of company B's routes, then the final price is 2*PriceofA + 1*PriceOfB. Also the weight of a edge is simply the price of the associated company.

This is a normal case so far, however, the following extra rule is making it difficult for me:

The 3rd company 'C' applies it's price ONCE regardless of how many routes it has in the final path, but it's price is usually higher than the previous companies. Therefore C's routes are ideal for longer paths, while A and B are best for shorter paths.

Here is what i have done so far (and why it does not work):

I am using Dijkstra to get the cheapest path and i have simply set the weights of each edge to be the price of the company. Even for C.

Then if the algorithm visits a node owned by C, it sets the weight of all the other edges that C owns to 0. Otherwise the algorithm continues as normal.

The problem is that Dijkstras algorithm always prioritizes the immediate best choice, and since company A and B have smaller prices than C, then it will try to avoid C. Sometimes this results in a path that the algorithm thinks is the shortest/cheapest, but in reality could have been much cheaper if it had chosen C to begin with.

How can i get the true cheapest path in this case?

Should i change to another algorithm? and if so, which one?

Comment: If you are using Dijkstra, C edges should come forward after you have visited say x*A or x*B, whatever multiple of A or B that makes them greater than C. Then the path including C moves forward in priority and is checked. Or if it never is checked it means that the multiple of A or B is still smaller than one C. Or am I missing something?

Comment: "Then if the algorithm visits a node owned by C, it sets the weight of all the other edges that C owns to 0. " Do you reset the weight if the edge Owned by C is unselected ? I.E. if another path is found no passing by that edge?

Comment: I'll try to rephrase what user1984 and AloisChisten have pointed out already: Dijkstra works fine in this case, but resetting C edges is not the right approach. Instead, in addition to tracking path length so far you need to also track whether it crossed a C edge. I can sketch this in Python if you wish

Comment: You say *edges* are owned by the companies, so what does "a *node* owned by C" mean? And if you take a path with three edges like CAC, do you have to pay only one C or two? If one, then I don't see the problem. Either you pay C or you don't, so run Dijkstra twice, once without C-edges and once with C-edges being free (but adding the C-cost to the total).

Answer (score 2):

One option here is to transform the original graph of flights to directly encode the idea that once you’ve taken a C flight, all future C flights are free.

For each airport x, create two nodes x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub>. The idea is that node x<sub>1</sub> corresponds to being in airport x without having ever taken a C flight, and x<sub>2</sub> corresponds to being in airport x having taken at least one C flight.

Now add edges as follows. For each A or B flight from an airport x to an airport y at price p, add an edge from x<sub>1</sub> to y<sub>1</sub> at price p and from x<sub>2</sub> to y<sub>2</sub> at price p. These correspond to taking A and B flights at their established price. Then, for each C flight from an airport x to an airport y at price p, add an edge from x<sub>1</sub> to y<sub>2</sub> at price p (this is where you pay the one-time cost of using C flights) and from x<sub>2</sub> to y<sub>2</sub> at price 0 (this flight is free now that you’ve already paid the up-front cost to use C flights).

If you run Dijkstra’s algorithm in this modified graph starting at a node x<sub>1</sub>, you can find the cheapest flight to an airport y by looking at the costs to get to y<sub>1</sub> (not using any C flights) and y<sub>2</sub> (using at least one C flight). The paths through the new graph will tell you which flights to take.

This doubles the size of the input graph, which will slightly slow down Dijkstra’s algorithm but won’t asymptotically affect the runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can keep a flag alongside the costs to each node that indicates you have already used a `C` flight or not. This flag will dictate whether the next `C` flight costs you or not.

In other words, instead of setting all the `C` edges to zero when you use a `C` edge, keep this local to the state of each tried path.

You could prioritize paths where the flag is set over other paths with equal costs but with an unset flag. This is a heuristic that helps your algorithm find the solution faster, but it would have done so nonetheless eventually.

Now, when you start Dijkstra, paths with `C` cost included will come forward in the priority queue as soon as a multiple of `A` or `B` paths cost at leas as much as a `C` path that includes a `C`. From there it's just a standard Dijkstra as far as I understand.